# download the artifacts of a gitlab build job to a remote server

Tags: ssh, gitlab, artifacts

I am attempting to download the artifacts of a build job from GitLab to a remote server. I have configured GitLab to connect to the remote server via SSH, and I have noticed that I can use the curl command to download artifacts from GitLab.

I have two questions:

First question: Will the artifacts be downloaded to the local machine or the GitLab runners I am using when using the curl command?

Second question: Is there any other method to store the generated artifacts.zip on the remote server, perhaps using SCP or other tools?

I have tested the connect between the Gitlab and the server using SSH it works. then I didn't succeed in downloading the artifacts.zip but still need to clarify where the artifacts.zip will be downloaded and after downloading it how can I move it to the remote server and extract it there.